# Check Upper or Lower Triangular Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there any way, using numpy or scipy, to check if a matrix is a lower or upper triangular matrix?. I know how make a function for check this; but I'd like know if these modules have   their own functions themselves. I'm searching in the documentation but I do not have found anything.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would do

```
np.allclose(mat, np.tril(mat)) # check if lower triangular
np.allclose(mat, np.triu(mat)) # check if upper triangular
np.allclose(mat, np.diag(np.diag(mat))) # check if diagonal
```

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html

Comment: greats! and to check diagonally?

Comment: any way to do this avoiding the copy?

Comment: I can't think of a way to avoid the copy with numpy. If this was a bottleneck in my code I'd try writing the test in cython or numba